# JavaScript addEventListener function with parameters

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is a way to pass a function with parameters into an JS `addEventListener`?

I have tried directly binding a function with parameters to `addEventListener`, but the listener does not work and executes the function right away without the event being triggered.

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", test1("text I would like to pass"));

function test1(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click Me</button>
```

The listener would work if the function bound does not contain any parameter:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", test1);

function test1() {
  console.log("text I would like to pass");
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click Me</button>
```

I have also tried doing the same thing using `onclick` but the same scenario happens. In that case, how do I bind a function with parameters to `addEventListener` then?

Comment: `.addEventListener("click", () => test("text i would like to pass"));`

Comment: Or `.addEventListener("click", test.bind(null, "text i would like to pass"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use () => { call your function here } or function(){ call your function here}

```js
document.getElementById("button1")
.addEventListener("click", () => { test1("four");});

function test1(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: How would you remove the eventListener in this case?